# Different download paths for different labels in uTorrent

Tags: windows, bittorrent, utorrent, p2p, label

I've been using Transmission for a pretty long time, and there was good feature which allowed me to put torrents with different labels into different folders. For ex. torrents with label music would go /users/my_profile/downloads/music

Is there anything similar in the Windows version of uTorrent\BitTorrent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Add persistent labels under `Options / Preferences / Advanced / User Interface`:

   [image: 1]
2. Then under `Options / Preferences / Downloads` select *Move completed downloads to* and especially **Append the torrent's label to the directory name**:

   [image: 2]
3. Finally assign each torrent a label according to its content as shown below and it ought to end up in your `Downloads_Dir\Label_Dir`:

   [image: 3]

Screenshots are from [here](http://torrentfreak.com/use-utorrent-to-organize-your-bittorrent-downloads/) so things may have moved around a bit, but those options are still very much there as per the [FAQ](http://help.utorrent.com/customer/portal/articles/164816-what-are-labels-and-what-can-they-be-used-for-).

Comment: Just a small note: latest version of utorrent removed that option, but it is still available from web gui

Comment: Ionut: checking that option in remote.utorrent.com should make effect in windows utorrent gui settings, right? So it should work even if it doesnt have the option?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, uTorrent supports organization in directories if you apply the label **before** the torrent completion. However, if you add/change the labels of your torrents **after** their completion, uTorrent will not move the files to the new directory. This makes space management of your uTorrent directory quite hard.

This python script can help you to re-organize your torrents after changing labels: https://github.com/m000/cliutils/blob/master/bin/utorrent_tidy.py. The only dependency of the script is a recent version of Python and the `bencode` Python module.

It works like this (assuming you are on a Mac - Windows should be straightforward to get right):

```
# uTorrent must be stopped!
killall uTorrent

# Rewrite resume.dat and move files using the script.
cp ~/Library/Application\ Support/uTorrent/resume.dat .
./utorrent_tidy.py resume.dat resume2.dat
cp resume2.dat ~/Library/Application\ Support/uTorrent/resume.dat

# restart uTorrent
open /Applications/uTorrent.app
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovered a workaround for the disappeared "Append the torrent's label to the directory name"

Enable your uTorrent's web interface, go to it using your browser, adjust the settings from there - the "append..." checkbox is still present in that interface, and it still works (just tested it).

How To: Link below.

Credits: stevew_f (uTorrent Forum User)

Removed in full from: http://forum.utorrent.com/topic/88673-label-rule-system-vs-append-the-torrents-label-to-the-directory-name/